# How to use vim in the terminal?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

How does one setup and start using vim in the terminal on OS X?

I want to start writing my C code using vim in the terminal rather than a separate text editor. How does one get started on this?

The basics like: opening, creating, saving files via terminal using vim and writing code using vim. Also, does one compile directly using vim in the terminal?

Comment: I doubt you can compile using vim. Vim is an editor not a compiler.

Comment: But he still can call an **external** compiler from vim, something like `:!gcc -o main main.c`, anyway it's important the fact that he **needs** an external compiler because vim is just a text editor.

Comment: Here is a great narrative tutorial http://vi-improved.org/tutorial.html

Comment: You could compile with Vim's built-in terminal too (recent feature in v8.1)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Run `vim` from the terminal. For the basics, you're advised to run the command `vimtutor`.

```
# On your terminal command line:
$ vim
```

If you have a specific file to edit, pass it as an argument.

```
$ vim yourfile.cpp
```

Likewise, launch the tutorial

```
$ vimtutor
```

Comment: Okay, but where is all of it's features then?

Comment: @EatonEmmerich ummm which features are you missing besides a GUI toolbar?

Comment: ex: run `:terminal`. OS X version has quite a lack of features.

Comment: That's not what this question is about. This is about running Vim within a terminal (as it was designed) instead of running gvim with a desktop GUI surrounding window.

Comment: @EatonEmmerich Ohhh you are talking about `:terminal`, a feature of _neovim_. That's not in basic Vim, which was the subject of this question.

Comment: looks pretty standard to me: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/ab350f89f9646e07aefe16a32ba3ddb847496b4a/src/feature.h#L1237

Answer (score 163):

## Get started quickly

You simply type `vim` into the terminal to open it and start a new file.

You can pass a filename as an option and it will open that file, e.g. `vim main.c`. You can open multiple files by passing multiple file arguments.

Vim has different modes, unlike most editors you have probably used. You begin in `NORMAL` mode, which is where you will spend most of your time once you become familiar with vim.

To return to `NORMAL` mode after changing to a different mode, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. It's a good idea to map your Caps Lock key to Esc, as it's closer and nobody really uses the Caps Lock key.

The first mode to try is `INSERT` mode, which is entered with <kbd>a</kbd>   for *append after cursor*, or <kbd>i</kbd> for *insert before cursor*.

To enter `VISUAL` mode, where you can select text, use <kbd>v</kbd>. There are many other variants of this mode, which you will discover as you learn more about vim.

To save your file, ensure you're in `NORMAL` mode and then enter the command `:w`. When you press `:`, you will see your command appear in the bottom status bar. To save and exit, use `:x`. To quit without saving, use `:q`. If you had made a change you wanted to discard, use `:q!`.

## Configure vim to your liking

You can edit your `~/.vimrc` file to configure vim to your liking. It's best to look at a few first ([here's mine](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc)) and then decide which options suits your style.

This is how mine looks:

[image: vim screenshot]

To get the file explorer on the left, use [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree). For the status bar, use [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline). Finally, the color scheme is [solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized).

## Further learning

You can use `man vim` for some help inside the terminal. Alternatively, run `vimtutor` which is a good hands-on starting point.

It's a good idea to print out a [Vim Cheatsheet](http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif) and keep it in front of you while you're learning vim.

Comment: Cheatsheet Link is down.

Comment: There's also [this](http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif) very good cheatsheet.

Comment: @LieuweRooijakkers Cheers, I will update my link to that one.

Answer (score 4):

You can definetely build your code **from** Vim, that's what the `:make` command does.

However, you **need** to go through the basics first : type `vimtutor` in your terminal and follow the instructions to the end.

After you have completed it a few times, open an existing (non-important) text file and try out all the things you learned from `vimtutor`: entering/leaving insert mode, undoing changes, quitting/saving, yanking/putting, moving and so on.

For a while you won't be productive at all with Vim and will probably be tempted to go back to your previous IDE/editor. Do that, but keep up with Vim a little bit every day. You'll probably be stopped by very weird and unexpected things but it will happen less and less.

In a few months you'll find yourself hitting `o`, `v` and `i` all the time in every textfield everywhere.

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

if you want to open all your `.cpp` files with one command, and have the window split in as many tiles as opened files, you can use:

```
vim -o $(find name ".cpp")
```

if you want to include a template in the place you are, you can use:

```
:r ~/myHeaderTemplate
```

will import the file "myHeaderTemplate in the place the cursor was before starting the command.

you can conversely select visually some code and save it to a file

1. select visually,
2. add w ~/myPartialfile.txt

when you select visualy, after type ":" in order to enter a command, you'll see "'<,'>" appear after the ":"

```
'<,'>w ~/myfile $
```

^ if you add "~/myfile" to the command, the selected part of the file will be saved to myfile.

if you're editing a file an want to copy it :

```
:saveas newFileWithNewName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn by reading yourself:

1. Open MacOS terminal app.
2. Write this and press enter -> ***vimtutor***
3. For quit write this and click -> ***:q***

Answer (score 0):

On Mac Just Press i button and start inserting and line