# git rebase - cannot change 'pick' to 'reword'

Tags: git, rebase, git-commit

I'm trying to change the commit message of a previous commit.  I'm trying to use `git rebase --interactive <commit>`

Once I find the commit I am looking for in the VIM window, when I use the arrow keys to locate the sha1 for the commit, delete the word `pick` and start to type 'reword' or 'edit' only some of the characters print and the cursor will jump to different parts of the commit message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5764079/1615903

Comment: thank you, that really helped

Comment: typing `i` to start to `insert` text allowed me to type, `esc` then `:wq` to save the changes

Answer (score 20):

Go to the particular line and use shift+i , text will become editable

Answer (score 15):

Follow these steps in editor

1) SHIFT + R = Replace / Edit Text

2) After replace text use **ESC**

3) Then Save ' **:WQ** '

Answer (score 2):

Probably having a bit of `vim` trouble. You might like a basic [vi introduction](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html), or perhaps just change the `git` editor to something you're comfortable with. Export an environment variable `EDITOR=/path/to/another/editor`, and `git` will use that instead of `vim`.