# Unsure how to type while trying to clone a repository I already have on github

Tags: git, github

I am a very new GitHub user with no previous programming experience. I am currently working on a project to make a website for my Linguistics professor, and I came across GitHub Pages which seems like a very promising way to accomplish my goal.

So far, I've created a repository and added a theme from Github Pages on [github](https://github.com). The current challenge I am facing came as I was trying to create a local repository (I think that means folder) on my computer from which I can use Atom to edit the Markdown file for the website. I went to my repository on github and clicked on 'clone or download' and then 'download zip'. Then, I put the folder that came out of opening the zip file on my desktop.

So I was following this [guide](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/2.): I successfully did a `git init`, but when I tried `git status`, I got a message asking me to confirm my email and username. This is the point where I am lost.

I typed in the command that terminal asked me to in order to confirm the username and email (I forget what the command was; I think something like `git config --something --something`). Both the email and username were wrong, and I tried to edit them. However, I can't seem to edit the text. Moreover, I can't get out of the window to where I previously was. I was pressing random buttons to get out, and ended up deleting where it had my username.[Here is a screenshot of where I am right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4BqY.png).

I'm just not sure how to edit the email or username within this window. This is what I am trying to figure out.

Moreover, I wanted to check whether I have to do any other steps to make sure that my local repository is connected to my github repository online. If I sign in with the same email and username I am using for my github account on this local repository, will the two be officially connected?

Thank you so much in advance,
Cody

Comment: instead of downloading the zip you could just have used `git clone <the url github gave you>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use vim in the terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764071/how-to-use-vim-in-the-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

You are in an editor called [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)). It do is very **NOT** user firendly at first. To start editing text press "i". Then do all your editing and then press escape once it's done type ":wq" and then press enter. Afterward i would recommend you change the default editor to something more *beginner friendly*. [How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits)